# What does this symbol mean in IntelliJ? (check mark between file icon and file name)

Tags: intellij-idea

In the project navigator in IntelliJ IDEA I have an icon similar to a check mark between the file icon and file name. I can't find any explanation in the  [Icon Reference](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/icons-reference.html?origin=old_help).

Does anybody know what it means?

[image: IntelliJ IDEA check mark between file icon and file name in Project Navigator]

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/symbols.html here's a list of the symbols

Comment: When something doesn't make sense, [file an issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-240929) for it to be clarified!

Answer (score 62, accepted):

It is a bookmark. Use menu item `Navigate > Bookmarks > Show Bookmarks` to show all your bookmarks.

Comment: Thanks for solving the riddle! But why would someone use a checkmark icon for bookmarks when there is a commonly accepted bookmark symbol!? [google "bookmark icon"](https://www.google.de/search?q=bookmark+icon)

Comment: If that bothers you, you may want to [file an issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues) about it:-)

Comment: Anyone know what it takes to make the checkmark go away after you remove the bookmark? Might happen eventually by itself, but it's certainly not happening right away in IDEA 2018.2, Build #IU-182.3684.101, built on July 24, 2018.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to remove it:

1. You can click on the folder and press <kbd>F11</kbd>.
2. You can click on the folder and then use the menu item: `Navigate > Bookmarks > Toggle Bookmark`

Comment: I think the person asking the question looks like they are asking what the symbol means - don't think the person is asking how to remove the icon.

Comment: I'm here trying to get rid of the darn thing.  Turns out it's F3 on MacOSX.